# want to connect gridview with firebase

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, android-layout, gridview

I have created gridview in a project I am working on . I want to connect my gridview with my firebase database so that I can dynamically add images in my gridview and can retrieve it so that my gridview gets updated with the latest images. Please reply if you could point me in the right direction.

this is my ImageAdapter.java code

```
public class ImageAdpater extends BaseAdapter {
 
    private Context mContext;

    public int [] imageArray = {R.drawable.b1,R.drawable.b2,R.drawable.b3,R.drawable.b4,R.drawable.b5,R.drawable.b6,
            R.drawable.b7,R.drawable.b8,R.drawable.b9,R.drawable.b10,R.drawable.b11,R.drawable.b12,
            R.drawable.b1,R.drawable.b2,R.drawable.b3,R.drawable.b4,R.drawable.b5,R.drawable.b6,
            R.drawable.b7,R.drawable.b8,R.drawable.b9,R.drawable.b10

    };



    public ImageAdpater(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return imageArray.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return imageArray[position];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
        imageView.setImageResource(imageArray[position]);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(340,350));
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

this is my mainpage.java code

```
    public class mainpage extends AppCompatActivity {

    GridView gridView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mainpage);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.grid_view);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdpater(this));


        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FullScreenActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("id",position);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        });

        Button video = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        video.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent k = new Intent(mainpage.this,bvideos.class);
                startActivity(k);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

this is my FullScreenActivity.java code

```
public class FullScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView imageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full_screen);

        imageView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);

        Intent i = getIntent();

        int position = i.getExtras().getInt("id");

        ImageAdpater imageAdpater = new ImageAdpater(this);

        imageView.setImageResource(imageAdpater.imageArray[position]);



    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I want to connect firebase with gridview ??how can I connect??

Comment: I want connection of gridview with firebase

Comment: And also  want to retrieve images from firebase storage which are stored in gridview

Comment: Ok, but what is the problem with the shared code?

Comment: no there is no problem .just want to incooperate firebase code in it